# Dual touch on a div element

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a program that requires a div element to act like a Mac's mousepad, one finger moves to move the cursor and another finger sends a click request. I am using HTML and JS for this webapp. my question, how can I achieve this?

what needs to happen is I need two fingers on the div at any time. if one finger is held and moved across the div, it updates X, Y variables however if a second finger taps the div, it will register as a click, allowing me to use the onclick event as normal.

I am building  a mouse app for android if that helps. also if jquery is required, i have that as well. Thanks in advance, let me know if this is a bit unspecific in the comments please :)

```
<div id="touchPad" 
     onmousedown="updateLocation()" 
     onmouseup="broadcastClick()" 
     onclick="broadcastClick()">
```

`updateLocation();` just sets X and Y variables to touch X and touch Y.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Please attempt the problem and post your code!

Comment: What site is this on?  I'm sorry this was meant for stack overflow :D

Comment: Sorry misread your post. please ignoreXD

Comment: Stack Overflow. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :P